# Tool Kit Image loader

Tags: java

i'm reading a book on java programming iv'e come to a part were i don't understand  it's loading a bit image or something here's the code

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
image = tk.getImage(getURL("castle.png"));
```

what is the get URl am i suppose to tell it where the image actually is or something?

how can it locate the image i get this error when i run it like it is -

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here's the full code -

```
package randomshapes;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RandomShapes extends JFrame{

  private Image image;

  public static void main(String [] args){
    new RandomShapes();
  }

  public RandomShapes(){
    super("DrawImage");
    setSize(600,600);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    image = tk.getImage(getURL("castle.png"));
  }

  private URL getURL(String filename){
    URL url = null;
    try{
      url = this.getClass().getResource(filename);
    } catch (Exception e){ }
    return url;
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 40, this);
  }
}
```

Comment: getURL(String url) is a method defined in your class executing this code. Can you show us more code?

Answer (score 0):

When loading images with Toolkit, the image is assumed to be located relative to your project root classpath.  I personally use and recommend using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) instead of Toolkit to load images.

For example, consider you have the following structure:

```
com
 -> example
     -> game
     -> util
resources
 -> images
 -> fonts
    --> image.png
```

To get your image.png as a BufferedImage using ImagoIO, you would simply do the following:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SomeClass.class.getResource("/resources/images.image.png");
```

The method is declared to throw IOException, but I'll leave the handling of it to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be very specific in my answer.  In this case, the "image load failure" is somewhat of a distraction in this case.  Look at method `getURL()` closer:

```
private URL getURL(String filename){
  URL url = null;
  try{
    url = this.getClass().getResource(filename);
  } catch (Exception e){ }
  return url;
}
```

The JDK method [`URL Class<T>.getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) returns "null if no resource with this name is found".  Simply put: The file `castle.png` is not found.  Learn more about resource paths from [this excellent blog post](http://technotes.tostaky.biz/2012/08/understanding-absolute-and-relative.html).

In the constructor `RandomShapes()`, this line fails with a `NullPointerException`:

`image = tk.getImage(getURL("castle.png"));`

Method `Image Toolkit.getImage(URL)` does not accept `null` inputs.

Assuming your class lives inside a JAR file, the URL returned will use the special "jar:" scheme, specifically designed by Sun for providing the location of a file inside a JAR.

If your image file is not stored in a JAR, you can use this trick to convert a file path to a URL: `URL myImageUrl = new File("/my/images/folder/castle.png").toURI().toURL()`

Do not be tempted to call `File.toURL()` directly; it is depreciated in favour of the `toURI().toURL()` technique.